# Drupal format Javascript to be included in theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to implement  http://jsfiddle.net/mgmilcher/8R7Xx/sho/ Responsive HTML5 Video Background in my Drupal Site Homepage but have been unsuccessful. I believe it has to do with the JS not being formatted correctly. Here is the custom JS I am trying to include on my theme.info file, using script [] = custom.js.

What is the proper way to format this? Currently everything this handles doesn't show up.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Resive video
    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        scaleVideoContainer();
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
    });

});

/** Reusable Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        videoWidth,
        videoHeight;

    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
            windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

        if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
            videoWidth = windowWidth;
            videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
        } else {
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
        }

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');


    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap all js code in

```
(function ($) {
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

So content of your custom.js should look like:

```
(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Resive video
    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    scaleVideoContainer();
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
});


/** Reusable Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
      windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      videoWidth,
      videoHeight;

    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
          windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

        if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
            videoWidth = windowWidth;
            videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
        } else {
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
        }

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');


    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, when I try and include this document, all of the classes that it formats wont display…at all. If I add this js in a <script> container on my html, the info is displayed fine. So I think the problem is with including this from an external js.

Comment: Still the same thing…If I add it in <script>…</script> on the page--front.tpl.php it works fine…but obviously this isn't best practice. Once I add it to the custom.js in /js folder and include it via scripts [] = js/custom.js in the theme.info file all the content disappears.